# Output values from the array in desired order?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have array with the multiple records, each record has ID, event name and customer name. My algorithm that I use does not seem to work the way I want. Before I start to loop through array I set the empty variable outside of the loop `var eventId;` then I started looping and inside of the loop I have multiple if statement. So if eventId is empty I want to append tr with event name and below that another tr with customer name. Then next time if my eventId is not empty I want to check if name match with the record, if they match I just want to append td inside of existing tr and output customer name. If they do not match I want to output new tr with event name and new tr with customer name. I have working example here, it looks like that I have `Test 1` outputted twice on the screen and I do not want that. I should have event name only once and all customers for that event below that event. 
Here is my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/dmilos89/t1v2r8jm/3/

Please if you see where my code is breaking let me know. I think that I have problem with appending elements or my algorithm is missing something. Thanks in advance.

Javascript code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var myRes = [];
    myRes.push({'myId':"42",'eventName':"Test 1",'rCustomer':"Mike, Allan"});

    myRes.push({'myId':"42",'eventName':"Test 1",'rCustumer':"Gates, Bill"});

    myRes.push({'myId':"19",'eventName':"Spring 2016",'rCustomer':"John, Bill"});

    myRes.push({'myId':"19",'eventName':"Spring 2016",'rCustomer':"Adams, Ron"});

    myRes.push({'myId':"31",'eventName':"May Test 1",'rCustomer':"Steve, Marie"});

    myRes.push({'myId':"42",'eventName':"Test 1",'rCustomer':"Ariel, Bill"});

    myRes.push({'myId':"32",'eventName':"Fall 2016",'rCustomer':"Ron, Nill"});

    myRes.push({'myId':"32",'eventName':"Fall 2016",'rCustomer':"Kim, Alen"});

    myRes.push({'myId':"32",'eventName':"Fall 2016",'rCustomer':"Will, Huges"});

    myRes.push({'myId':"32",'eventName':"Fall 2016",'rCustomer':"Seth, Peak"});

  var eventId = '';
    var count = 1;

  for(var i=0; i< myRes.length; i++){
        if(eventId != ''){
            if(eventId == myRes[i].myId){
                $('#row_' + count).append('<td>'+myRes[i].rCustomer+'</td>');
            }else{
                eventId = myRes[i].myId;
                count++;
                $('.myReservation').append('<tr><td><b>Event: '+myRes[i].eventName+'</b></td></tr>');
                $('.myReservation').append('<tr id="row_"'+count+'><td>'+myRes[i].rCustomer+'</td></tr>');
            }
        }else{
            eventId = myRes[i].myId;
            $('.myReservation').append('<tr><td><b>Event: '+myRes[i].eventName+'</b></td></tr>');
            $('.myReservation').append('<tr id="row_"'+count+'><td>'+myRes[i].rCustomer+'</td></tr>');
        }
    }
});
```

HTML code:

```
<table>
  <tbody class="myReservation">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What about posting relevant code in question itself???

Comment: @A.Wolff I don't see the point of writing the code twice, I created working example with all data needed for testing.

Comment: If in the futur you get other issue and search through this site and find a similar question with answer and both point to any external dead links, you'd get the point of always posting relevant code in question...Now you have more than 500 in rep, you should know that.

Comment: Ok, thanks for advise.

Comment: I don't have time to write a solution for you, but my first thought is that your problems arise because your data is in no particular order. It would be more straightforward to create subarrays for each event that contains only the objects that are part of that event, and then render each subarray out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misplaced the double quote when inserting `tr` elements with ids.

Replace `<tr id="row_"'+count+'>` with `<tr id="row_'+count+'">`.

**Update:** this achieves what you (probably) want:

```
var found = [];

for (var i = 0; i < myRes.length; i++) {
  if (found[myRes[i].myId] === 1) {
    $('#row_' + myRes[i].myId).append('<td>' + myRes[i].rCustomer + '</td>');
  } else {
    found[myRes[i].myId] = 1;
    $('.myReservation').append('<tr><td><b>Event: ' + myRes[i].eventName + '</b></td></tr>');
    $('.myReservation').append('<tr id="row_' + myRes[i].myId + '"><td>' + myRes[i].rCustomer + '</td></tr>');
  }
}
```

Comment: I changed that in my code but I'm still getting Test 1 twice in the table.

Comment: If you want each event to have its own section, then your whole `eventId` system cannot work (and is superfluous): if you want all events of the same type to end up in the same section, just put a unique id there too and use that as a reference when appending users.

Comment: Can you provide example of how that should look like?

Comment: So you created empty array outside of the loop, then you check if array has any elements. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. The purpose there is just to know if a certain event already has a section; there are many ways to achieve the same effect, but that was the quickest I could think of.

Comment: But why you are trying to compare id inside of the array found to 1? That is something that I can not understand.

Comment: It's just the value that is put into it in the `else` branch: a boolean would have worked just as well (better, probably).
You could also invert the if logic using a `typeof found[myRes[i].myId] == 'undefined'` type of check.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you append a new element on every loop:

First, you are testing if "eventId" is not empty. If it is, you are setting it with the current loop iteration "myId"

```
eventId = myRes[i].myId;
$('.myReservation').append('<tr><td><b>Event: '+myRes[i].eventName+'</b></td></tr>');
$('.myReservation').append('<tr id="row_"'+count+'><td>'+myRes[i].rCustomer+'</td></tr>');
```

According to your data, **eventId** is now **42** and your output is :

```
<tr><td><b>Event: Test 1</b></td></tr>

<tr id="row_" 1=""><td>Mike, Allan</td></tr>
```

(by the way, there is a syntax error here and it explains why the next iteration doesn't append data)

Then, on the next iteration, **eventId** is still **42** so you are doing this

```
$('#row_' + count).append('<td>'+myRes[i].rCustomer+'</td>');
```

The output is the same at this point (see above the syntax error on the first answer)

On the next loop iteration, **myId** will be now **19** so you are overriding   **eventid** and appending tr in consequence

loops keep going...

Until **myId** is again equal to **42** :

```
myRes.push({'myId':"42",'eventName':"Test 1",'rCustomer':"Ariel, Bill"});
```

Here you doesn't want "Event: Test 1" appearing two times, but on the last loop iteration **myId** was **31**

```
myRes.push({'myId':"31",'eventName':"May Test 1",'rCustomer':"Steve, Marie"});
```

So on the if test, **eventId** is **NOT** equal to **myRes[i].myId**, therefore your script appends a new tr with duplicate event.

One solution could be this one:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        var myRes = [];
        myRes.push({'myId':"42",'eventName':"Test 1",'rCustomer':"Mike, Allan"});   
        myRes.push({'myId':"42",'eventName':"Test 1",'rCustomer':"Gates, Bill"});                   
        myRes.push({'myId':"19",'eventName':"Spring 2016",'rCustomer':"John, Bill"});                   
        myRes.push({'myId':"19",'eventName':"Spring 2016",'rCustomer':"Adams, Ron"});                   
        myRes.push({'myId':"31",'eventName':"May Test 1",'rCustomer':"Steve, Marie"});                  
        myRes.push({'myId':"42",'eventName':"Test 1",'rCustomer':"Ariel, Bill"});                   
        myRes.push({'myId':"32",'eventName':"Fall 2016",'rCustomer':"Ron, Nill"});                  
        myRes.push({'myId':"32",'eventName':"Fall 2016",'rCustomer':"Kim, Alen"});                  
        myRes.push({'myId':"32",'eventName':"Fall 2016",'rCustomer':"Will, Huges"});                    
        myRes.push({'myId':"32",'eventName':"Fall 2016",'rCustomer':"Seth, Peak"});


        myRes.forEach(function(value, key) {

            var table = $('.myReservation2');
            var elemInTable = table.find('tr#row_'+value.myId); // $('#row_42') as an example

            // If row doesn't exists, create it with it's customers
            if(!elemInTable.length) { 
                table.append('<tr id="row_'+value.myId+'"><td>'+value.eventName+'</td></tr>');

                elemInTable = table.find('tr#row_'+value.myId);
                elemInTable.after('<tr><td>'+value.rCustomer+'</td></tr>');
            }
            // If it already exists, simply add the customers
            else {
                elemInTable.after('<tr><td>'+value.rCustomer+'</td></tr>');
            }

        })
    });
```

However, I don't think it is the proper way to do it, actually, I think that you should reorganize your data (if your context permits it) like this :

```
myRes.push({'myId':"42",'eventName':"Test 1",'rCustomer': ["Mike, Allan", "Gates", "Bill", "..."]})
```

(sorry for my english by the way)

Comment: I appreciate your time to help me with this code. So what is your solution in this case? I should not check if eventID is equal and do this != if it's not?